# How would I make this triangle inside a circle (in TikZ)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

This is what I'm going for, detailed in the image above. Additionally, how would I rotate the triangle if necessary?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You will find that a properly posed question should show some effort, providing self-contained compileable code that demonstrates what you have tried to this point.  Questions of the sort, "do this for me" are generally not well received, as they leave all the work up to those who might otherwise try to help you.

Comment: @Zarko I've tried a few things out, as I'm not really familiar with TikZ, so I tried using GeoGebra to generate it for me, but I'd like to know a way of adding letters to the TikZ picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your starting point and my exercises and fun :) ...

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[rotate=30]
\def\radij{22mm}
\coordinate (center) at (0,0);
\draw   (center) circle (\radij);
\draw   (center) -- (\radij,0) -- node[right] {$d$} (\radij,2*\radij) 
                 -- node[left,pos=0.25] {$h$} 
                    node[left,pos=0.75] {$r$} cycle;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for making it easily editable, too!